# Need to transfer an excel table in Power BI and automate calculations

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, data-analysis, m

I am a beginner to Power BI and just getting a hang of DAX queries and M Language. I would like to automate some calculations and transfer tables from my Excel sheet to Power BI. The table I am working with is as follows:

[image: Table]

This table is connected to another sheet that populates the columns: yesterday, today and MTD (Month to date).
The Target column is also entered manually, but new customer targets collectively need to amount to 100,000. Subsequently, that is how the Variance, Current DRR and DRR are calculated (DRR - Daily Run Rate).
In excel, this is depicted as a merge of rows, but can the same be done for Power BI?

[image: Table and Formula]

Additionally, the Client, Yaumi Bakeries' transactions need to be split into Existing and New based on the new customer orders put in after a certain date. So 3000 of any amount assigned to Yaumi Bakeries is a new client, while the rest is Existing. The data entered for Yaumi Bakeries from the source does not have this distinction and hence cannot be changed at that level.

Any help or advice in these matters would be appreciated.

Comment: Very broad solution question - break it down into smaller questions with where you are getting stuck. In the meantime, Power BI isn't a worksheet/spreadsheet, what does the raw data look like and where does it come from? Is it refreshable?